Error in executing gcloud commands in bash script in crontab
I have written a bash script that uses
gcloud command to activate service account and
gsutil command to move files to GCS bucket.
When I run the script using bash command, it executes well.But when I place the script in crontab , it fails with command not found.
==> NOTE: You are uploading one or more large file(s), which would run
significantly faster if you enable parallel composite uploads. This
feature can be enabled by editing the
"parallel_composite_upload_threshold" value in your .boto
configuration file. However, note that if you do this large files will
be uploaded as `composite objects
<https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects>`_,which
means that any user who downloads such objects will need to have a
compiled crcmod installed (see "gsutil help crcmod"). This is because
without a compiled crcmod, computing checksums on composite objects is
so slow that gsutil disables downloads of composite objects.

Removing file:///file.csv
Operation completed over 1 objects/2.7 GiB.

/script.sh: line 691: gcloud: command not found
/script.sh: line 693: gsutil: command not found 

What is the mistake here. How do I correct it

Add your cronjob to your question.

What directory are those commands in? By default, cron jobs run with a PATH containing only /bin and /usr/bin, so if they're anywhere else (and you don't add the relevant directory to PATH), they won't be found. See "crontab and binaries in /usr/local/bin" and if that doesn't solve it, "CronJob not running" has more troubleshooting recommendations.

The issue is with the PATH. Thanks to below answer. It worked after explicitly exporting gcloud path with in the script.
gcloud command not found - while installing Google Cloud SDK
export PATH="~/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"


Don't put the ~/ inside quotes, it causes problems depending on exactly how the command is invoked. Use either export PATH=~/"google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH" or export PATH="$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH". See "tilde expansion when evaluating $PATH".
